# Creating GA4 tag using Google Tag Manager REST APIs

Tags: google-api, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

We have a website and want to migrate our Universal Analytics tags to GA4 tags. But want to avoid manually migrating Universal Analytics tags to GA4 tags. Got to know about Google Tag Manager (GTM) REST APIs for creation of tags, triggers etc. As part of POC, I am able to create Universal Tag using REST API, documented [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/tags/create).

But not able to create GA4 tags from the GTM REST APIs. Used below request payload:

```
{
  "name": "GA4 Tag",
  "type": "gaawe",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "type": "template",
      "key": "measurement_id",
      "value": "G-1234567890"
    },
    {
      "type": "template",
      "key": "event_name",
      "value": "page_view"
    },
    {
      "type": "list",
      "key": "custom_dimensions"
    }
  ]
}
```

Getting 400 Bad request error as below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "vendorTemplate.parameter.measurementId: The value must not be empty.\nvendorTemplate.parameter.eventName: The value must not be empty.\n",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "vendorTemplate.parameter.measurementId: The value must not be empty.\nvendorTemplate.parameter.eventName: The value must not be empty.\n",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

But the documentation ([link](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/tags/create)) does not mention any `vendorTemplate` as required or optional parameter. Still I tried adding `vendorTemplate` as one of the attribute in request payload then it says `Property "vendorTemplate" does not exist in object specification`.

Since I am not able to create GA4 tag using REST API, I'm far away from trying migration of Universal Tag to GA4 tag.

Need help regarding creation of GA4 tags and migration of Universal Analytics Tags to GA4 tags using REST APIs.

I tried resolving `vendorTemplate` error by adding it to request payload. Was expecting it to work but it gave different error which is, `Property "vendorTemplate" does not exist in object specification`. Did not find any documentation regarding creating GA4 tag using REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common misunderstanding in GTM REST API.

We need to know that

1. The GTM API document only cover how to create a `Tag`
2. But it is not covering how to create a `Tag` Like GA4 Event Tag.

There are more detail in GA4 event tag or other tag.

**The best way for me is : Creating a tag in the UI first. Export it and look how the JSON is. Then try to assemble it**

Here is a example of GA4 event tag JSON from export.

```
{
    "accountId": "accountId",
    "containerId": "containerId",
    "tagId": "6",
    "name": "tagName",
    "type": "gaawe",
    "parameter": [
        {
            "type": "TEMPLATE",
            "key": "eventName",
            "value": "stay_time"
        },
        {
            "type": "LIST",
            "key": "eventParameters",
            "list": [
                {
                    "type": "MAP",
                    "map": [
                        {
                            "type": "TEMPLATE",
                            "key": "name",
                            "value": "abc"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TEMPLATE",
                            "key": "value",
                            "value": "100"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TAG_REFERENCE",
            "key": "measurementId",
            "value": "GA4_G-000000000"
        }
    ],
    "fingerprint": "1657085557584",
    "firingTriggerId": [
        "0"
    ],
    "tagFiringOption": "ONCE_PER_LOAD",
    "monitoringMetadata": {
        "type": "MAP"
    },
    "consentSettings": {
        "consentStatus": "NOT_SET"
    }
}
```

Looks like you missing this part

```
{
    "type": "TAG_REFERENCE",
    "key": "measurementId",
    "value": "GA4_G-000000000"
}
```

The value is the name of the GA4 config tag. If you don't have it. You need to create the GA4 Config tag first(through UI or API both are fine)

---

Here is the example of the GA4 config tag :

```
{
    "accountId": "{{accountId}}",
    "containerId": "{{containerId}}",
    "tagId": "4",
    "name": "{{tag_name}}",
    "type": "gaawc",
    "priority": {
        "type": "INTEGER",
        "value": "1000"
    },
    "parameter": [
        {
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "key": "sendPageView",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "type": "BOOLEAN",
            "key": "enableSendToServerContainer",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "type": "TEMPLATE",
            "key": "measurementId",
            "value": "{{measurementId}}"
        }
    ],
    "fingerprint": "1663432050222",
    "firingTriggerId": [
        "2147479553"
    ],
    "tagFiringOption": "ONCE_PER_LOAD",
    "monitoringMetadata": {
        "type": "MAP"
    },
    "consentSettings": {
        "consentStatus": "NOT_SET"
    }
}
```

Replace the {{variable}} with your's and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I tried inspecting request payload while creating GA4 Config tag and tried using that JSON in REST API. But there is one attribute called `vendorTemplate` but while passing it through API payload it gives an error saying  "Property "vendorTemplate" does not exist in object specification". So could not create the GA4 Config tag.